# How to generate click event of anchor tag on enter key press in textbox

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

I am developing a JSP page where I have many anchor tags. So I have put a text box where I can search all the anchor tags on my page. I am using Javascript.

Now what I need is when I text an anchor tag name in the text box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key it should work as `onclick` of that particular anchor tag .

I have tried the below code but it did not work for me:

```
<script>
function searchkeypress(e)
{
if(typeof e=='undefined'&& window.event){e=window.event;}
if(e.keycode==13)
document.getElementById("search").click();
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="searchkeypress(event)"/>
<a id="search" href="#Ajax" onclick="index.jsp"/>
```

Comment: so if i understand correctly, if i type "search", it finds an anchor with ID "search", and redirects the page according to it's location?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('index').click()"/>
<a id="index" href="index.jsp"/>
```